# Hibernate very slow with Multiple @OneToOne relationships

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am having a problem with Hibernate. The problem is that some of the queries take too long time to execute. 
I found that one of the Entities "Client" has 3 Relationships @OneToOne to another Entity "Address" - for different type of addresses : "managementAddress", "correspondenceAddress" and "buildingAddress". In the Entity of "Address", there is no Relationship to the "Client" entity. I figured out the the slow loading comes from these Relationships.
The @OneToOne relationships are initialized Eagerly. I am not allowed to changed the Model Relationships. Does anyone have idea how could I increase the speed of Execution? Thanks.

This is how the Relationships Are declared in "Client" entity:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Address managementAddress;
```

This is a sample from the Hibernate statistics, for loading 50 "Client" entities:

```
7248515 nanoseconds spent acquiring 51 JDBC connections;
2583681 nanoseconds spent releasing 51 JDBC connections;
43894536 nanoseconds spent preparing 203 JDBC statements;
4106621728 nanoseconds spent executing 203 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
```

Comment: If it is multiple queries enable show_sql in persistence.xml and go through one by one by executing in DB manually in the main time check database logs and profile if possible

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and it seems that Hibernate generates multiple Select statements to retrieve the 3 addresses for every Client. There should be some way to optimize this fetching process, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark it will `FetchType.LAZY` to lazy load addresses only when required.

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Address managementAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Addresses are very often used, so even if I mark them as Lazy, I will have to load them on multiple pages. Wondering if there is a way to optimize this Relationships fetching?

Comment: If you configure Caching properly in your ORM will be not be loaded multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, the caching helped a lot.